# Oracle function call from VB6. Function is not a procedure error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, vb6, oledb

I have Oracle function declared as

```
create or replace FUNCTION CheckScan(
  pMode IN number, 
  pAgrISN in number, 
  pAgrId in varchar2, 
  pDocISN in number, 
  pRefundId in varchar2) RETURN NUMBER IS  ...
```

And client Visual Basic 6 code that connects to Oracle as administrator like:

...

```
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "CheckScan"
cmd.CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc

Dim pMode As Integer
Dim pAgrISN As Integer
Dim pAgrId As String
Dim pDocISN As Integer
Dim pRefundId As String

pMode = 2
pAgrISN = 12345
pAgrId = "Some-Id"
pDocISN = 12345
pRefundId = "Some-id"

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("pMode", 131, 1, 10, pMode)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("pAgrISN", 131, 1, 10, pAgrISN)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("pAgrId", 200, 1, 255, pAgrId)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("pDocISN", 131, 1, 255, pDocISN)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("pRefundId", 200, 1, 255, pRefundId)

cmd.Execute
```

This code ends with:

```
PLS-00221: "CHECKSCAN" is not a procedure or is undefined
```

What is wrong here? Function was compiled successfully.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the user that is connecting to the Oracle DB have EXECUTE permission on the function? Also the function is returning a value, are you capturing it?

Comment: Yes, it's an adminstrator account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a function (and not a procedure), you have to do something with the return value. Add the following parameter:

```
With cmd
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRetval", adNumeric, adParamReturnValue)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pMode", adNumeric, adParamInput, 10, pMode)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pAgrISN", adNumeric, adParamInput, 10, pAgrISN)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pAgrId", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, pAgrId)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pDocISN", adNumeric, adParamInput, 255, pDocISN)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRefundId", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, pRefundId)

    .Execute
End With
```

**Update:**

The order of the parameters is relevant. It must start with the return type. Then all parameters of the function must follow in the order they were declared. The names of the parameters are irrelevant however because positional (and not named) parameters are used internally. This is obvious if you look at the `CommandText` property of `cmd`:

```
"{ ? = call CheckScan(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }"
```

Comment: Thank you, @Codo! i have refactored code with 4 (return value) parameter - now it returns: PLS-00306 (Wrong number or types of arguments in a call to "CHECKSCAN") ... Do I correctly pass parameters?

Comment: @AndrewFlorko: I think you misunderstood my code. You need five parameters: four input parameters and one return value. The fifth parameter needs to have a numeric type since your function is declared to return a NUMBER.

Comment: No, No I have 6 parameters (5 input + 1 return value) at the moment.

Comment: @AndrewFlorko: It seems to be important that the return value parameter is added as the first parameter. I've updated my answer to show a full example.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply caused because you have defined it as a function, but are calling it as if it was a procedure. Either call it as a function (with `SELECT`), or use an `IN OUT` parameter in place of `RETURNING`.

Comment: Thank you, @Gaius, i have refactored code with 4 (return value) parameter - now it returns: PLS-00306 (Wrong number or types of arguments in a call to "CHECKSCAN") ... Do I correctly pass parameters?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can call a function by itself.  Instead, I'd try executing a select, something like:

```
select CheckScan(:pMode, :pAgrISN, :pArgId, :pDocISN, :pRefundId) from dual;
```

Comment: Nice...I was going to ask him to do that, too.

Answer (score 1):

What does this function do?  Oracle has certain restrictions on functions (not allowed to do updates in certain situations, etc...).  [Check out this doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5009.htm), and make sure you're not violating anything under the **Restrictions on User-Defined Functions** section.  You might have to create it as a stored procedure (or wrap it with one).